# how to implement the core animation layer property in code

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, xib, nib

I set the `Core Animation Layer` of `NSButton` in the xib file, like below:
[image]

I'd like to know how to set it in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a looks at the description of setWantsLayer. It explains what to do.

You either want to call setWantsLayer:TRUE, or first call setLayer, then setWantsLayer:TRUE, depending on what you want to do with layers.

Comment: setWantsLayer: is not I want as I tried it. Could you describe more about how to setLayer? Should I create a new layer?